# How to display list of data in application?

Tags: flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I have encountered an error where the data is printed out in terminal but do not display in the application.

```
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getTeacher() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User");
    var query = docRef.where("type", isEqualTo: "teacher").limit(10);
    query.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc["name"]);
        print(doc["email"]);
      });
    });
  }

    body: new FutureBuilder(
          future: getTeacher(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: Text(snapshot.data["name"])),
                        Expanded(child: Text(snapshot.data["email"])),
                        Expanded(
                            child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.chat), onPressed: () {}))
                      ],
                    );
                  });
            }
            return Container();
          }),
```

[image: this is error i get after running the apps]
[this is the output in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1BW5.png)

Comment: Check doc is not null before print

Comment: act the doc is already print out in the terminal. but not display in the apps

Answer (score 1):

Your `getTeacher()`-Function does not return your Future. Because of this
the Nullpointer-Exception ist thrown. You should return `query.get()` instead of listen to it.
You should also not call `getTeacher()` in the build-Function because it will be called at every build.

EDIT:

Your method:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getTeacher() async {
   var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
   var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User");
   var query = docRef.where("type", isEqualTo: "teacher").limit(1);
   return (await query.get()).docs[0];
}
```

Variable of your widget:

```
final Future<DocumentSnapshot> teacher = getTeacher();
```

Your FutureBuilder:

```
new FutureBuilder(
      future: teacher,
      builder: ...
)
```

Comment: what should i do? can u explain more? im sorry im still beginner :(

Comment: If you're going to return only the first document, you can save some money/bandwidth by using `.limit(1)` instead of `.limit(10)`.

Comment: im getting error for ;

final Future<DocumentSnapshot> teacher = getTeacher();

return query.get().docs[0];

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from future function. Please check below code

```
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getTeacher() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
    QuerySnapshot query =
        await docRef.where("user_device_language", isEqualTo: "en").limit(10).get();

    return query.docs;
  }
```

And handle null value in list view like this

```
   body: new FutureBuilder(
            future: getTeacher(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(child: Text(snapshot.data[index]["name"])),
                            Expanded(child: Text(snapshot.data[index]["email"])),
                            Expanded(child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.chat), onPressed: () {}))
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                } else {
                  return Text('No Data');
                }
              }
              return Container();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: thankyou. al ready displayed the data but, how to display all the data? since the output only displayed 1 data.

Comment: @fizahpanda103 I've edited above code. Please check.

Comment: @fizahpanda103 Please make sure the value at snapshot.data[index]["name"] is not null other it's gonna throw error. You have to manage null value with if else statement